# Python compress all files/images/sounds in one executable file with py2exe

Tags: python, file, bundle, exe, py2exe

When I tried to convert my Pythonprogram into an exe with py2exe, first everything works fine until I tried to bundle all files into one single executable file. First all the images and sounds are not bundled, but in the distfolder. I have the same problem with a .dll file, witch I have to import manually for the programm to work. So how do I import all the files like images, dll's and sounds into the exe? Next when I try to execute the exe like this, it gives me this error in cmd:

`Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
 This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
 Please contact the application's support team for more information.`

Here is my setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import Tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
import pygame
import random

import glob

setup(
    data_files=[("libogg-0.dll"),
                ('.', glob.glob('*.gif')),
                ('.', glob.glob('*.wav'))],
    options = {"py2exe": {"includes": ['Tkinter', 'random', 'itertools', 'pygame'],
                          "excludes": ['AppKit', 'Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'Foundation', 'Numeric', 'OpenGL.GL', 'OpenGL.GLU', 'RandomArray', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'copyreg', 'dummy.Process', 'numpy', 'opencv', 'pkg_resources', 'psyco', 'queue', 'test.__main__', 'test.event_test', 'test.test_utils', 'test.test_utils.async_sub', 'test.test_utils.run_tests', 'test.test_utils.test_runner', 'test.test_utils.unittest_patch', 'urllib.parse', 'vidcap', 'win32api', 'win32con', 'win32file', 'win32pipe', 'winreg','pygame.sdlmain_osx'],
                          "dll_excludes": ['OLEAUT32.dll','USER32.dll', 'IMM32.dll', 'SHELL32.dll', 'ole32.dll', 'COMDLG32.dll', 'COMCTL32.dll', 'ADVAPI32.DLL', 'WS2_32.dll', 'GDI32.dll', 'WINMM.DLL', 'KERNEL32.dll', 'SDL_ttf.dll', 'libogg-0.dll'],
                          "packages": ['pygame'],
                          "bundle_files": 1,
                          "compressed": True
                         }
              },
    console=['test.py'],
    zipfile = None
)
```

If there is still something unclear, feel free to comment a answer. Sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: You might take a look at this site:  http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/python/pkg_resources-with-py2exe.html.  It contains a recipe for getting py2exe to include specific files in the archive file.  I haven't tested it with single-file executables, I always use `bundle_files: 2` to produce a zip archive so multiple exe's can share a library archive, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to import `py2exe`.

Second, type `python -m auto_py_to_exe` and then the screen appears. There, chose the file by browsing and choose `in one file` and `console based` and then convert.

Hope this helps.